# Experience Cloud - Redirect to Page After Login Not Respecting my Login Component's Start Url Parameter?

Tags: community, lightning-community, experience-cloud, b2b-lex

We are using B2B LEX, which lives off of an Experience.  We have a requirement where after login, we need to redirect the user to a specific page in the Experience - this page is different from the home page.  Using the 'Start Url' parameter on the default login component seems like it should do the trick, but it doesn't always act as expected - sometimes when you login it redirects you correctly, other times it doesn't.  I've narrowed this down to happening when you click the "Login" button that takes you to the login page; when you do this, it sets a `startUrl` parameter in the url which seems to trump anything I define on the component.  If I log out and immediately log back in, because the `startUrl` parameter isn't specified in the url, it goes to the page I specified in the component, as expected.  I've tried commenting out the `startUrl` page references in the default Apex classes (`SiteLoginController`, `CommunitiesLoginController`, `LightningLoginFormController`), even trying to hard code the value but the behavior doesn't change (an error would have been welcome at this point)!  Is there something I'm missing here?  How do I redirect the user to the page specified in the component?

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround; they provide you a custom Aura component called `loginForm` that isn't visible by default; in the `.cmp` file they have this comment:

```
<!-- add implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" to surface the component in community builder -->
```

I did that, and it seems like it's pretty much functionally the same as the default 'Login Form' component.  I gave it the start url I wanted, and while there was still that pesky `startUrl` parameter in the url in the browser, the one I defined on the component level superseded that it seems.  Frankly I'm not sure why that doesn't work for the default out-of-the-box component, and if anyone has any ideas please chime in.